# GetType does not accept itemStack

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I'm writing a crafting plugin and I need to check if `getResult().GetType()` is equal to `ItemStack`, but `getType()` probably does not accept the `ItemStack`.

```
ItemStack its = new ItemStack(Material.getMaterial(s.getInt("item")),   
1, (byte) s.getInt("data"));
if(e.getInventory().getResult().getType().equals(its)) { //this don't work
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't work because `e.getInventory().getResult().getType()` returns `Material` object and `its` in your case is `ItemStack` object. So if you want to check if just the items' types are equal, you have to write:

```
    if(e.getInventory().getResult().getType().equals(its.getType())) {
      //code here
    }
```

or if you want to do such a comparison like you presented in your post you have to compare `ItemStack` objects as you cannot compare `ItemStack` object to `Material` one. Then you have to write something like this:

```
    if(e.getInventory().gtResult().equals(its)) {
      //code here
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you help me, and tell me how to check if the player has done crafting with help? I mean Event Result? `if(Result.ALLOW`

Comment: What do you mean by 'do crafting with help'? What exactly want to check?

Comment: in PrepareItemCraftEvent check if he created the item, if it does, then something happens next. Because I check the amount of items needed to create, but after creation, you have to delete them.

Comment: You mean the moment when player grab crafted item from the slot or you just want to prevent crafting item if there is no proper amount of ingredients needed? Because I can't still understand what you exactly want to do.

Comment: Yes, it is about the moment when player grab crafted item from the slot.Sorry, but I don't know how explain. I need to check, if player grab crafting item.

Comment: You have to use `InventoryClickEvent` and in this event check player, clicked item and type of inventory to ensure if there is a crafting action and then check/do whatever you want to. I highly recommend you to read the docs as there is everythig what you want there: https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/event/inventory/InventoryClickEvent.html